# Do I need publish_stream scope to delete invitation requests?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, scope, request

I'm using `FB.ui({method: 'apprequests', ... })` to let users invite their friends to my java web app.

In the Facebook Requests Dialog documentation it says that I need to delete the request when the user has accepted the request:

> When a user is directed to your application, by clicking a Request
>   from the application, the games dashboard, or from a Request
>   notification, you must delete the request after it has been accepted.
>   Requests are not automatically deleted once they have been clicked,
>   thus it is the developer’s responsibility to clear them once they have
>   been consumed.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#deleting

When I try to do this with the [RestFB Graph API Java client](http://restfb.com/) I get a permission error from facebook.

The code:

FacebookClient client = new DefaultFacebookClient(appAccessToken, new DefaultWebRequestor(), new DefaultJsonMapper());
client.deleteObject(String.format("%d_%d", requestId, facebookUserId));

The log says:

> (com.restfb.DefaultWebRequestor) INFO: Executing a POST to
>   graph.facebook.com/XXX_XXX with parameters (sent in request body):
>   method=delete&access_token=XXX&format=json&locale=en_US

The error:

> Facebook responded with HTTP status code 403 and response body:
>   {"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions
>   error","type":"OAuthException"}}

I have tried both app access token and receiving user's access token, and I have scopes email and publish_actions. I read somewhere that I may need the publish_stream scope. I would rather not ask my users for that just to be able to delete requests, though? Or is it something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need publish_stream to remove requests sent by your app to a user - have you tried using the App Access Token?

Comment: Yes, I have tried both app and user access tokens. I have updated the description with code and log rows.

Comment: It may be that you have a bug - you could file it in Facebook's bug tracker where you'd be able to include the access tokens and request IDs safely - to me that code all looks fine so i can't see why it's failing

Comment: Okay, thanks. Does it matter if I'm in sandbox mode?

Comment: It shouldn't; if it does that's a bug - sandbox mode should work fine for this

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the publish_stream scope if you use the APP Token.

If you use the C# facebook SDK you can use this:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(Config.FacebookAppId, Config.FacebookAppSecret);
var result = fb.Delete(string.Format(
  "{0}_{1}?access_token={2}",
  facebookRequestId,
  facebookUserId,
  fb.AccessToken
));
```

(See also: [Facebook Deleting Requests](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13857108/facebook-deleting-requests/16790579#16790579))